# Excel VBA - Run through multiple row, if a row is blank, enter a section of headers

Tags: vba, excel, nested-loops

I'm writing a macro to sort through a large file of data at work. I've inserted a blank row at the top of different section of data. I want my code to realize when a row is blank in column C, then fill in a set of headers in that row. It should then continue to find the next blank in column C. This should continue until my code finds 2 consecutive blanks, which signals the end of my data.

Currently, my code inserts the desired headers, but only in the first row of my worksheet. I believe that I need to change the loop contained inside my "Do... Loop Until" function. I just can't seem to get the correct code to achieve my desired results.

I've included a screencapture of roughly what my spreadsheet will look like.  [image]

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub AddHeaders()

'Add headers below each section title
Dim Headers() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long, Row As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'turn this off for the macro to run a 
little faster

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveCell = Cells(1, 3)

Headers() = Array("Item", "Configuration", "Drawing/Document Number", 
"Title", "ECN", "Date", "Revisions")
' Set Do loop to stop when two consecutive empty cells are reached.
Do
For Row = 1 To LastRow 'Add a loop to go through the cells in each row?
    If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True Then 'If row is empty, then go in and add headers
        For i = LBound(Headers()) To UBound(Headers())
            Cells(Row, 1 + i).Value = Headers(i)
        Next i
        Rows(Row).Font.Bold = True
'Loop here
    End If
Next Row

ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) And IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn it back on



MsgBox ("Done!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
I removed the activecell stuff and used range instead.
Also removed the do loop and only use the for loop.
I think it works but Not sure. It does not look like you have on your picture but I keept your text code.

```
Sub AddHeaders()

'Add headers below each section title
Dim Headers() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long, Row As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'turn this off for the macro to run a


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveCell = Cells(1, 3)

Headers() = Array("Item", "Configuration", "Drawing/Document Number", "Title", "ECN", "Date", "Revisions")
' Set Do loop to stop when two consecutive empty cells are reached.

For Row = 1 To LastRow 'Add a loop to go through the cells in each row?
    If Range("C" & Row).Value = "" Then 'If row is empty, then go in and add headers
        For i = LBound(Headers()) To UBound(Headers())
            Cells(Row, 1 + i).Value = Headers(i)
        Next i
        Rows(Row).Font.Bold = True
'Loop here
    End If
Next Row



Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn it back on



MsgBox ("Done!")
End Sub
```

Edit; Include image of output of above code.
[image]

Comment: I've since updated my code.  Now instead of adding a header above each blank row cell in column C, it adds headers for every row, overriding the data my macro has entered thus far.  Any ideas on how I can fix this issue?

Comment: How should I know? You have updated the code.... I can't possibly know how you updated the code. I think you should start a new question since this question is answered and done. You don't keep updating questions as time goes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
Sub AddHeaders()
  Dim nRow As Integer

  nRow = 1
  Do Until Range("C" & nRow) = "" And Range("C" & nRow + 1) = ""
    If Range("C" & nRow) = "" Then
      Range("A" & nRow & ":D" & nRow) = "Header"
    End If
    nRow = nRow + 1
  Loop

End Sub
```